# How do I pipe stdout and std error to a file and back to stdout on Windows?

Tags: windows, logging, pipe, stdout, tee

On Windows when running a batch script I want to record the output of I run:

```
myprogram.bat 1> mylog.log 2>&1
```

Which is great - but I have to run a separate tail process to read the output in another window. What I want is to be able to record it to a file and see it in the window all at once.

Now on a mac I can do this with:

```
./a.out 2>&1 | tee output
```

My question is: **How do I pipe stdout and std error to a file and back to stdout on Windows?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that is possible. You can either use a 3rd-party tool, such as [WinTee](https://code.google.com/archive/p/wintee/):

```
myprogram.bat | wintee "mylog.log"
```

or switch to PowerShell and use [Tee-Object](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937.aspx) cmdlet:

```
.\myprogram.bat | Tee-Object "mylog.log"
```